# Animate div's CSS top property when scrolling down

Tags: javascript

I have a notification that pops up during difference instances on my site, and I'd like that notification to follow the menu that animates when you scroll down.

The code I have is as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var messageFollow = $('.woocommerce-info').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= messageFollow) {
        $('.woocommerce-info').css({top: "150px"});
    } else {
        $('.woocommerce-info').css({top: "74px"});
    }
});

</script>
```

The notification has a value right now of `top: 150px` which looks great when you're at the top of the screen but `top: 74px` looks great when scrolled down.

I also want it to **animate**, but I have no idea how to implement that as well.

A clip to demonstrate: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6i95f5gkbyn4nm/MessageNotification.mov?dl=0

Comment: Is it possible to share a website link or Fiddle?

Comment: Is this good enough? As you'll see the notification does not follow the menu as gets smaller when scrolling downwards: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6i95f5gkbyn4nm/MessageNotification.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a built-in [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

Just replace `css` with `animate` and make sure the value is integer.
You can also give a duration in milliseconds as a second parameter to animate function.

```
$('.woocommerce-info').animate({top: 150},500);
```

Comment: Thank you for that! So I don't need the .css tag if I use .animate?

Comment: Yes, you don't need .css if you use .animate.